# Showing $kP(k,0)+(k+1)P(k,1)+...+(k+n)P(k,n)=P(k,n+1)-k$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation

Define: $P(k,0)=k$

$P(k,i)=k.(k+1)....(k+i-1)(k+i)$

> Can you show that:
>
> $$k.P(k,0)+(k+1).P(k,1)+...+(k+n).P(k,n)=P(k,n+1)-k$$

**Example:** $k^2+k(k+1)^2+k(k+1)(k+2)^2+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)^2+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)^2=k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)-k$

**Special case:** if $k=1$ then:

$1.1!+2.2!+3.3!+4.4!+....+n.n!=(n+1)!-1$

Comment: Have you written your question correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, my guess is that what you want to prove is not what you wrote. It is$$k.P(k,0)+(k+1)P(k,1)+\cdots+(k+n)P(k,n)=P(k,n+1)-k.$$Note that $P(k,n)=\frac{(k+n)!}{(k-1)!}$. So, you want to prove that\begin{multline*}k\frac{k!}{(k-1)!}+(k+1)\frac{(k+1)!}{(k-1)!}+\cdots+(k+n)\frac{(k+n)!}{(k-1)!}=\\=\frac{(k+n+1)!}{(k-1)!}-k=\frac{(k+n+1)!-k!}{(k-1)!}.\end{multline*}Of course, this is equivalent to$$k.k!+(k+1).(k+1)!+\cdots+(k+n).(k+n)!=(k+n+1)!-k!.$$This is easy to prove by induction on $n$. If $n=0$, this is just $k.k!=(k+1)!-k!$. Now, take $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that what you want to prove holds for that $n$. Then\begin{multline*}k.k!+(k+1)(k+1)!+\cdots+(k+n+1).(k+n+1)!=\\=(k+n+1)!-k!+(k+n+1).(k+n+1)!=\\=(k+n+1).(k+n+2)!-k!.\end{multline*}

Comment: Perhap $P(k,n)=\frac{(k+n)!}{(k-1)!}$, but the proof is true, thank to You very much

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you think that it is correct, then perhaps that you might signal it as an accepted answer.